# How to write a message if I need a new job (searching/looking, contact me/turn on me)

Tags: word-choice

Which makes more sense?

> Don't hesitate to turn on me  / Don't hesitate to contact me

Also,

> I am searching for a new job  /   I am looking for a new job

Comment: Yes and I dont understand -1 rating by someone? I thought that is pretty clear question.

Comment: As for the -1, no idea why. The formatting and 'thanks' didn't fit the site's style guidelines but they should have just edited it.

Answer (score 8):

For the first, the correct choice is:

> Don't hesitate to contact me.

and for the second, both are correct.

This is because "turn on me" has the meaning of "attack me", so this would be inappropriate if you were looking for a job.

The second two mean the same, and are both appropriate.

Comment: To clarify: "turn on" has the meaning of attack if the object is a person: "turn on him", "turn on me". Otherwise, it means something else: "turn on the light", etc. (@Thursagen: I'm sure you know this but your readers might not)

Comment: Not shinynewbike, Mr. Shiny and New. Dunno who that other guy is :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Don't hesitate to turn on me
```

To "turn on [someone]" means to betray.  It's perfectly good English; I just doubt it's what you mean.

To "turn [someone] on" means to sexually arouse.  I will leave it to your own judgment whether it would be better to tell a potential employer to betray you or to arouse you, but I don't think either is a very good idea.

```
Don't hesitate to contact me
```

This seems to accurate convey what I guess you mean.  Strunk & White condemned "contact" as jargon; they have bad reputation on this site, but I think they have a point.  *How* should the person contact you?  If they can call or email you, write:

```
Don't hesitate to call or email me
```

As for

```
I am searching for a new job / I am looking for a new job
```

The distinction is one of intensity: "search" is intense, "looking for" isn't.

In John Ford's 1958 classic *The Searchers*, two men (Walter Coy and John Wayne) spend 10 years obsessively tracking down the Indians who kidnapped their niece.  There's never been a movie called *The Lookers-For* but if there were, it would feature Seth Rogan and Justin Long as two guys vaguely curious about where they left their sunglasses but not enough to get up from the couch.

If you want a more neutral words, consider "seeking a new job".

Answer (score 3):

Beware that *don't hesitate to turn on me* resembles *don't hesitate to turn me on* very closely, a phrase which is extremely sexual. You don't want to use that, trust me.

This is perfectly grammatical:

> Don't hesitate to contact me.

As for the second sentence, *I am looking for a new job* is your best choice there. Notice the missing indefinite article in your original sentence.

Comment: There is nothing sexual about the phrase *turn on someone*, the problem is that it means *become aggressive towards*.  Word order is everything here.

Comment: I never said there's anything sexual about the phrase *turn on someone*.

Comment: RiMMER, the fact that "turn on me" resembles "turn me on" is a bit irrelevant, I think. I don't think it's a common mistake to misuse those (at least I've never heard it). The problem with "turn on me" is that it's completely wrong for the questioner's context.